# ActionScript 3 Sharedobject class data lost

Tags: actionscript-3

I used a shared object class to save some view data. When I move the SWF file, all the shared object data is lost.

The questions are:

1. Is this expected behavior of sharedobject class?
2. Is there any other way to save data that stays with the local or SWF.

Comment: Fixed grammar, layout, removed sign-off. Clarified questions.

Comment: awesome, thank you @BobDalgleish

Answer (score 0):

SharedObject Data is stored on the local machine, in a specialised sandbox. If you move SWF to another machine or launch it in another OS (i.e. in a virtual machine) of course you will not have the same SharedObject data available. This also applies to launching SWF from a browser (SO data is still saved locally. Acess the same site from another machine and it will be gone).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The same lost data behavior when i move to a new folder file?

Comment: When you move to a new folder file it shouldn't. It also depends on your SharedObject name, do you set it yourself? Or you let the SWF generate it automatically?

Comment: This is the SharedObject class script that i use.

var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("Stopwatch");